# error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Vector2D&' from an rvalue of type 'Vector2D'

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue

Here is the code, CodeBlocks indicates the error is on the line shwon:

```
bool SoccerTeam::isPassSafeFromOpponent(Vector2D    from,
                                        Vector2D    target,
                                        const PlayerBase* const receiver,
                                        const PlayerBase* const opp,
                                        double       PassingForce)const
{
    Vector2D ToTarget = target - from;
    Vector2D ToTargetNormalized = Vec2DNormalize(ToTarget);

    Vector2D LocalPosOpp = PointToLocalSpace(opp->Pos(),
                                             ToTargetNormalized,
                                             ToTargetNormalized.Perp(),
                                             from); // *** ERROR ***
```

Error message:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Vector2D&'
from an rvalue of type 'Vector2D'`
```

Comment: Add the declaration for `PointToLocalSpace` so we can comment on whether the params are incorrect

Comment: store `ToTargetNormalized.Perp()` in a local variable, and replace this expression within `PointToLocalSpace` with this variable, probably same with `opp->Pos()`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the 3rd parameter, where you try to pass the return value of Vector2D::Perp() function as reference. (The same could apply to the first parameter either, but I guess that's a const Vector2D&, so it probably won't cry.) Try the following:

```
bool SoccerTeam::isPassSafeFromOpponent(Vector2D    from,
                                        Vector2D    target,
                                        const PlayerBase* const receiver,
                                        const PlayerBase* const opp,
                                        double       PassingForce)const
{
    Vector2D ToTarget = target - from;
    Vector2D ToTargetNormalized = Vec2DNormalize(ToTarget);
    Vector2D ToTargetNormalizedPerp = ToTargetNormalized.Perp();

    Vector2D LocalPosOpp = PointToLocalSpace(opp->Pos(),
                                             ToTargetNormalized,
                                             ToTargetNormalizedPerp,
                                             from);
```

Comment: That has fixed the issue, thanks for your help. Great community!